# Suggest ways to convert Rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, macros, vba

I have an excel file that has 3000 rows. I want to convert a part of these rows into columns. Is there a macros to do this or can this be done in SQL server? Please suggest.

Below is the sample data:

[image]

This has to be converted as below:

[image]

Typically, 2 things: 1. The column names added and existing will have their names changed. 2. The record count is too huge, but headers names must be as shown in the picture. 3. Only part of rows are converted into columns. so there's the glitch. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Akasha, have you tried anything so far? If so, please can you post what you've tried? It might be worth re-wording your question as I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking for. Have you explored paste transpose? Edit: I get what you mean and I think it's probably better to re-write your SQL query to fit the format you want, rather than run it then mess with it in Excel.

Comment: I have not tried anything until now. I was using Pivot for smaller count of rows. But for larger count I'm still exploring to see the ways.

Comment: @stevenwalker you mean to import this file in sql and do the querying? And does pivot work for such large entries?

Comment: Sorry when you mentioned SQL server I presumed this was an outcome of a query you had written. Yes, pivot works with rows of 3000 and if it displays in the format you require then it's your ideal solution - don't write a macro if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I'll try that for my sample data and then for the main file.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with Pivot (there's also Unpivot).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Put this in cell A7:

=OFFSET(INDIRECT("A"&ROW(A1)*2-1),INT((COLUMN(A1)-1)/9),MOD(COLUMN(A1)-1,9))

Fill right.